# AzMonitor workbook to visualize data by city

Tags: maps, data-visualization, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

One is able to group the number of page views by country, per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-map-visualizations#using-countryregion). PFB KQL query.

```sql
    pageViews | project client_CountryOrRegion, itemCount, client_City
```

However, visualizing by `client_City` doesn't work.

[image]

Is there a way one could group and visualize by the name of the city instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbooks *itself* doesn't currently have any built in mapping of city to lat/long, we only have that at the country/region level.  (In the screenshots above, you told workbooks that a column of data has country information, but then you passed it cities, so it doesn't  know of any countries named those things)

there are various ways to do it by using the `externaldata` operator in ADX/Log Analytics to have the database load, parse, and join with your other data.  If you can get to lat/long, then you can tell workbooks to use that mode where you tell it which columns are lat and long and you'd have your points.

not the exact files you want, but in another example someone wanted to map from ip address to country, and in that example you'd add something like this to your query:

```
let geoData = externaldata
(network:string,geoname_id:string,continent_code:string,continent_name:string,
country_iso_code:string,country_name:string,is_anonymous_proxy:string,is_satellite_provider:string)
[@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoip2-ipv4/master/data/geoip2-ipv4.csv"] with (ignoreFirstRecord=true, format="csv");
geoData
| limit 10
```

in your real query you'd not have the limit, you'd use the kql `join` operator to do an intersection and you'd get your lat/long that way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. One needs to find the relevant city-related data and go from there. I'm wondering if this would be easier in PowerBI.

Comment: Is it documented that 'Workbooks doesn't have built-in mapping for cities'? I ended up having to use PowerBI. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi#export-an-analytics-query

Comment: its "implicitly" documented by the case that there's no option in the settings to tell workbooks you have city values.  the only options are lat/lon, azure location, azure resource, and country/region, where we know how to map things to coordinates.